# Maven mudando o faces-config.xml

Tags: java, jsf, maven, ejb

Tenho um projeto EJB e meu maven fica mudando o faces-config.xml quando eu executo o "mvn install", o maven muda tudo que tem dentro dele deixando sem os caminhos que eu especifico, segue meu arquivo "pom" do projeto WEB

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>WEB</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <basedir>${project.basedir}</basedir>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>br.com.empresa</groupId>
        <artifactId>Pai</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- dependencia de projetos -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>EJBClient</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
            <artifactId>seguranca</artifactId>
            <groupId>br.com.empresa/groupId>
            <version>1.14</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>utilitarios</artifactId>
            <groupId>br.com.empresa</groupId>
            <version>1.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>batch-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>br.com.empresa</groupId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- commons -->
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ibm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
            <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
            <version>52.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.j2ee</groupId>
            <artifactId>j2ee</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0.29</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-ibm</artifactId>
            <version>20100702_1406</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>classworlds</artifactId>
            <groupId>classworlds</groupId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
            <groupId>plexus</groupId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <version>3.11</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.websphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>sitelib</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0.21</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webappDirectory>WebContent</webappDirectory>
                    <webXml>WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <!-- <archive> -->
                    <!-- <manifestFile>WebContent/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile> -->
                    <!-- <manifest> -->
                    <!-- <addClasspath>true</addClasspath> -->
                    <!-- </manifest> -->
                    <!-- </archive> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

O que poderia ser?

Comment: Su XML está mal-formado. Na segunda dependência está faltando o `<dependency>` logo após o `</dependency>` da primeira dependência. Isto daqui também está errado: `<groupId>br.com.empresa/groupId>`, pois falta o `<` antes do `/groupId>`.

Comment: Você está usando alguma IDE? Já tive problemas aonde a IDE alterava arquivos como esse automagicamente. No fim, não era o maven o culpado.

Comment: To usando o RSA, que eh uma versao do eclipse da ibm, mas ele "formata" o faces-config.xml na hora que eu executo o "mvn install" pelo prompt comando, nao e pelo RSA. O maven mexe de alguma maneira no faces-config.xml?

Comment: O maven não deveria estar mexendo neste arquivo a menos que alguma coisa muito incomum esteja acontecendo. Mas a IDE pode detectar o maven executando e então mexer no arquivo. Se você fechar o RSA completamente e rodar o `mvn clean install` pelo prompt, o que acontece?

Comment: Ele continua apagando o faces-config.xml, eu realmente não tenho a minima ideia do que pode ta acontecendo, poderia ser algum plugin, ou alguma coisa do tipo

Comment: Se você colocar o `faces-config.xml` como somente-leitura e rodar o maven, dá pau em alguma etapa do processo?

Comment: Ainda não tentei isso, como eu coloco o faces-config.xml somente como leitura?

Comment: O sistema operacional tem a possibilidade de marcar arquivos como somente-leitura.

Comment: Aparace esse erro, quando eu mudo a configuração somente pra leitura: Could not copy webapp sources [C:\Users\Documents\workspace\Projeto\Web\WebContent]: C:\Users\Documents\workspace\Projeto\Web\WebContent\WEB-INF\faces-config.xml (Acesso negado.) -> [Help 1]

Comment: Este erro é bom, e significa que o arquivo não pôde ser substituído. O maven apresenta um stacktrace? Se sim, edite a pergunta para adicioná-lo, pois neste caso o stacktrace vai denunciar qual foi a ação do maven que tentou sobreescrever o arquivo. Além disso, coloque também qual é o caminho completo do seu arquivo `faces-config.xml` que não deveria ser alterado.

Answer (score -1):

No meu caso eu fiz isso:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-war.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>WebContent\WEB-INF\</directory>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        <includes>
                            <include>faces-config.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Podes traduzir e explicar a resposta pf?